# Using a single field in Oracle SQL with multiple JSON values inside. How slow is it to query this?

Tags: sql, json, oracle

We currently have an audit table of the following form:

```
TABLE(timestamp, type, data, id) -- all the fields are of type varchar / clob
```

The issue is that for some `type`s there are actually several well suited `id`s. We currently only store one of those but it would be interesting to be able to query by any of those ids while still keeping only one column for that.

With Oracle's recent support for JSON we were thinking about maybe storing all the `id`s as a JSON object:

```
{ orderId:"xyz123"; salesId:"31232131" }
```

This would be interesting if we could continue to make queries by `id` with very good performance. Is this possible? Does Oracle allow for indexing in these kind of situations or would it always end up being a `O(n)` text search over all the millions of rows this table has?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although you can start fiddling around with features such as JSON types, nested tables and the appropriate indexing methods, I wouldn't recommend that unless you specifically want to enhance your Oracle skills.

Instead, you can store the `id`s in a junction table:

```
table_id    synonym_id
  1            1
  1            10
  1            100
  2            2
```

With an index on `synonym_id, table_id`, looking up the synonym should be really fast.  This should be simple to maintain.  You can guarantee that a given synonym only applies to one id.  You can hide the `join` in a view, if you like.

Of course, you can go down another route, but this should be quite efficient.

Comment: We use this just as a dump. We aren't really interested in using this as a normalized database.

Comment: @devouredelysium . . . If you want to search by the ids, I wouldn't call it a "dump" but a "database".

Answer (score 0):

1)Oracle's JSON support allows functional indexing on the JSON data (b-tree index on JSON_VALUE virtual column.)
2) for non-indexed fields the json date needs to be parsed to get to the field values. Oracle uses a streaming parser with early termination. This means that fields at the beginning of the JSON data are found faster than those at the end.